# XNA - How to move skinned model and merge animations

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, skeletal-animation

After you helped me to resolve my loadContent problem I've wrote some code and made 3D model with animation. Because XNA 4.0 doesn't support .fbx with multiple animations I've generated 3 models with different animations:
1. Start animation ( when you press arrow for the first time)
2. walk animation ( when you still hold it)
3. stop animation ( when button is up)

And here comes my question. How to apply those 3 models to work with arrows. 
Now I'm using to render animations (http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-us/education/catalog/sample/skinned_model )

```
 protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Load the model.
        currentModel = Content.Load<Model>("end_R");

        // Look up our custom skinning information.
        SkinningData skinningData = currentModel.Tag as SkinningData;

        if (skinningData == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException
                ("This model does not contain a SkinningData tag.");

        // Create an animation player, and start decoding an animation clip.
        animationPlayer = new AnimationPlayer(skinningData);

        AnimationClip clip = skinningData.AnimationClips["end_R"];

        animationPlayer.StartClip(clip);
    }
```

file with model and animation's name is identical.

I have also second question :) How to get model position from or how to move this model? Now it's connected with camera coordinates but I'd rather prefer the model to have it's own coordinates and transform it independently from camera.

Comment: Some part of my problem resolved. I've found out about XNA 4.0 Refres which supports multiple clips from one model. Still I don't know how can I get coordinates from my model and move it along the world or change animations in runtime